# How do you configure a datasink into a SOAP UI datasource loop?

Tags: soapui

I understand how to do point and click property transfer, but I'm not sure how to do it in a loop.

Take the attached image as an example of a working datasource loop where I'm able to read every row of a datasource (db or spreadsheet).

How do I make every request for every row of the datasource write one line to a datasink?

Currently the datasink only writes to one line.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out you must provide a worksheet name. It can't be blank. This seems like a bug but I'm not a pro user so I can't log the bug.

Answer (score 0):

Create a data source loop as the test step. It will loop the data so you can run the requests for each row

[image]